# Calculation results depend on simulation time (LTSpice)

Tags: ltspice

I am trying to simulate a circuit with several neonbulbs. And I have notified that the results I get depend on the simulation time described in the '.tran' command. An example is in the picture below. In an 80-second simulation, the same peak (at the same time) has about 180 nA, with a simulation time of 200 s, the peak has 90 nA. This is not the only example of this difference. This is just one of many and it completely blocks my project. I don't know what real value is. Moreover, I cannot compare different values. Please help me. [image]

Comment: First off, you should be able to provide some theoretical predictions. You should not just depend upon simulation (most of the time, anyway.) Second off, have you tried changing the maximum time step, yet? Make it something small.

Comment: Thank you very much, I belive it can help me.

Comment: What @jonk said, plus you have to account for the values you are using: *micro*, *Mega*, (tens, hundreds of) *seconds*. The dynamic range is quite large and, since the circuit is linear (save the internal switches), the simulation will tend to fly with large steps, all related to the total simulation time. This is why an imposed timestep will be needed in such cases.

Comment: I'm not sure what LTspice does specifically, but historically if you don't specify a [maximum time step](http://ltwiki.org/LTspiceHelp/LTspiceHelp/_TRAN_Do_a_non_linear_transient_analysis.htm) or a `tstep` it uses `tstop/50.0` as the default.  It also forces timesteps near where your PULSE source transitions...but your rise/fall times are set to zero.  I don't remember what LTspice uses as defaults if you leave those at zero.  Best to actually specify values there.  Also, are those "kiloseconds" you're trying to use there?